# How to insert data from file into HBase table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I made example.nt which looks like below.

```
    1 "aaaaa1" "bbbbb1" "ccccc1"
    2 "aaaaa2" "bbbbb2" "ccccc2"
    3 "aaaaa3" "bbbbb3" "ccccc3"
    .......
```

I want insert this data into HBase table which consist of

```
    (key int,subject string,predicate string,object string)
    (:key,cf1:val1,cf1:val2,cf1:val3)
```

I want perform this inserting on the hbase shell.
How can I do this?

Comment: you may want to consider inserting data in hbase table via hive, check this  link and try it out https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HBase shell` is not designed for these purposes, it allows insert data to HBase only line by line with put commands.

Instead of this you can use `importtsv` tool which allows you import text data directly to HBase.

Assuming you have already created HBase table `so_table` with one column family `cf1` and your `example.nt` file is in the `/tmp/example/` HDFS directory. So it's possible to use it by the following way:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf1:val1,cf1:val2,cf1:val3 so_table /tmp/example/
```

May be you will need add option to change column separator:

```
-Dimporttsv.separator=';'
```

Furthermore you should understand that this way data inserts to HBase directly via many put command. There is another way to use `importtsv` tool which is well suitable for bulk loading big amounts of input data. You can generate StoreFiles and then load it entirely to HBase with `completebulkload` tool:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=/tmp/example_output -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf1:val1,cf1:val2,cf1:val3 so_table /tmp/example/
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles /tmp/example_output so_table
```

You can read official documentation of this tool: https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_importtsv

Comment: When I tried your first suggestion, all lines look like bad lines. or When I tried your second suggestion, If I tried LoadIncrementalHFiles command, the result is there is no file... Is there a rule with file? Each line of my file(example.nt) is composed of rowkey subject predicate object. And each columns are separated by space(" ")

Comment: I tried importtsv and detected that it doesn't work with space (" ") separator, but works with any other separator (semicolon, comma, etc). Can you change your data separator from space to any other?

Comment: I tried change separator (tab), but another problem occured. like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977224/hbase-bulk-loading-error) Can you commnet this?